# Prove $f^{\log_a g}=g^{\log_a f}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

> Prove $f^{\log_a g}=g^{\log_a f}$

$$
y=f^{\log_a g}\implies \log_fy=\log_ag\implies g=a^{\log_fy}\\
g^{\log_a f}=a^{{\log_a f}.{\log_f y}}=a^{{\log_af}.{\log_ag}}=a^{{\log_ag}.{\log_af}}=a^{\log_af^{\log_ag}}=f^{\log_ag}
$$
Is it the right way to prove it ?

Comment: It seems like you can do it without introducing another variable.

Comment: Note that $f^\frac{\log_f g}{\log_f a}=(f^{\log_f g})^{\log_a f}$.

Comment: You recieved 3 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Comment: It's really rude to just abandon questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$$x^y = a^{\log_a(x^y)}=a^{y\cdot \log_a x}$$

Answer (score 0):

The function $y = \log_a x$ is one-to-one. Alternatively you could show that both sides have the same logarithm base $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y = \log_{a}(g)$ so that:

$$f^{\log_{a}(g)} = f^{y} = g^{\log_{g}(f^y)} = g^{y\log_{g}(f)} = g^{\log_{a}(g)\log_{g}(f)}$$

If we can show:

$$\log_{a}(g)\log_{g}(f) = \log_{a}(f)$$

we are done.

Observe:

$$\log_{a}(g)\log_{g}(f) = \log_{a}(g)\frac{\log_{a}(f)}{\log_{a}(g)} = \log_{a}(f)$$

Thus,

$$g^{\log_{a}(g)\log_{g}(f)} = g^{\log_{a}(f)}$$

(You can do this without introducing $y$, but I think it is easier to see with $y$)